# -watch on package.json does not work

Tags: css, sass

I can not run `"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"` (`--w` as well) in my `package.json`. Every time, I am trying to do that, I have error:

```
{
  "status": 3,
  "message": "File to read not found or unreadable: D:/Other Stuff/GRIDs/sass/main.scss",
  "formatted": "Internal Error: File to read not found or unreadable: D:/Other Stuff/Coding/GRIDs/sass/main.scss\n"
}
```

Sometimes, it's working until the first change and then error. I was trying `-w`, `--w`, `--watch`, `-watch`. Zero reaction:(

What shall I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure but did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164678/node-sass-wont-work-when-using-the-watch-flag)? Because the question there is same with yours.

Comment: It look like the path to the file is wrong. Fix that and it should work unless there is another error